# Bizarre python set comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, set

I face a strange problem where set comprehension won't work as intended.

```
b=[[2,9,10],[3,7,15],[5,12,12],[15,20,10],[19,24,8]]
print({(R, 0, 0) for _, R, _ in b})
```

We have output

```
{(12, 0, 0), (9, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0), (20, 0, 0), (24, 0, 0)}
```

Not the desired answer

```
{(9, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0), (12, 0, 0), (20, 0, 0), (24, 0, 0)}
```

What went wrong? For list comprehension, it works fine.

```
b=[[2,9,10],[3,7,15],[5,12,12],[15,20,10],[19,24,8]]
print([(R, 0, 0) for _, R, _ in b])
```

We have output

```
[(9, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0), (12, 0, 0), (20, 0, 0), (24, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Sets are not ordered by insertion order like you seem to want, they are unordered

Comment: those outputs are equal. What is wrong with them?

Comment: Thank you all. I originally thought set would preserve order. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural to have sets comprehension looks like this. Based on Iain and juanpa's comment, sets are not ordered. The order is not preserved. So that's why we have "unintended" print value.
On the other hand, if you want to preserve the order, you should use lists.

Comment: `dict`s will preserve order as of 3.6 (as implementation detail)/3.7 (as language guarantee). It's often possible to construct a `dict` with keys you don't care about that mostly behaves like an insertion-ordered `set`. See the duplicates I linked.